# jQuery Animate on Android nested div not moving

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

This issue seems to affect android only.

I'm working on a phonegap App for a client and I have a scrolling area using jQuery animate. However one of the nested divs doesn't move with it's parent div and stays fixed in position.

Again this issue only presents on android devices and works fine in desktop browsers and iOS.

Can anyone shed any light on what this may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems jQuery animate runs into issues with relatively positioned items, removed relative position and used margin and it seems to work now.